# how to display total records found in ssrs before view the report

Tags: reporting-services

I have created a report that returns results based on my date parameters `@startDate` and `@Enddate`. I want to be able to get a result that shows the totals number of records found before actually viewing the report.
How do I add a count function to count totals records found. then add a hyperlink action to open the report?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion to do this:

1. Encapsulate the query in a view or stored procedure.
2. Create a main report what does something like:

   `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyView WHERE myDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @Enddate`
3. Show the `First` result of your dataset (the count) in a textbox
4. Set an action to navigate to a subreport (see below) passing the same parameters
5. [Create a subreport](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160348%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) with a query like this:

   `SELECT * FROM MyView WHERE myDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @Enddate`
6. Show a tablix with the data in the subreport.

Optionally include a link back to the main report, etc.

Comment: Okay the count action works,but I would like the report in a new window(using the Go to Url action option) which however just shows me the fields example =First(Fields!bob_bobitemname ) .How can I manipulate it to show me all the fields using the date parameters and filters I used?